lightning record picker throwing error in production
I am using the lightning-record-picker component in my LWC, to search Asset records. This is the code:
<div class="slds-var-m-around_small"><lightning-record-picker label="Unidad a revisar" value={assetId} object-api-name="Asset" filter={assetFilter} onchange={handleAssetSelection} required></lightning-record-picker></div>

The filter criteria:
assetFilter = {
    criteria: [
        {fieldPath: 'ProductFamily', operator: 'eq', value: 'Le Parc Punta del Este - Torre IV'},
        {fieldPath: 'Estado_de_revision__c', operator: 'ne', value: 'Revisado sin observaciones'}
    ]
}

This works perfectly on my sandbox org, we tested it several times before deploying to production. But then, when using my component on our production org, the component fails, throwing the following error:
{
  "message": "Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'where.and[1]' with value 'ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='and', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='or', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Name', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='like', value=StringValue{value='%fam%'}}]}}]}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='ProductFamily', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='eq', value=StringValue{value='Le Parc Punta del Este - Torre IV'}}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Estado_de_revision__c', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='ne', value=StringValue{value='Revisado sin observaciones'}}]}}]}]}}]}' contains a field not in 'Asset_Filter': 'ProductFamily' @ 'uiapi/query/Asset'",
  "output": [
    {
      "errorType": "adapterError",
      "error": [
        {
          "extensions": {
            "ErrorType": "ValidationError"
          },
          "locations": [
            {
              "column": 9,
              "line": 5
            }
          ],
          "message": "Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'where.and[1]' with value 'ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='and', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='or', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Name', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='like', value=StringValue{value='%fam%'}}]}}]}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='ProductFamily', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='eq', value=StringValue{value='Le Parc Punta del Este - Torre IV'}}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Estado_de_revision__c', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='ne', value=StringValue{value='Revisado sin observaciones'}}]}}]}]}}]}' contains a field not in 'Asset_Filter': 'ProductFamily' @ 'uiapi/query/Asset'",
          "paths": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

What I understand is that this is a GraphQL error, but that's about it. I don't know what the error message means, I get that it has something to do with the field "ProductFamily" in Asset, but why does it work in sandbox and not in production? I checked the picklist values to see if there was any inconsistencies between orgs but it is all the same, and I couldn't find any other info about this error.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Have you checked for access to the ProductFamily field for the user that is running the component in Production?

@CallumMacErlich we are actually testing the component from our admin user, so I inmediatly disregarded any permissions or access issues.. do you believe this could be a problem anyway?

I would always check those first. Having admin access doesn't automatically grant field level access on objects.

@CallumMacErlich that was it! thank you very much for the help

Thanks to the recomendation by @CallumMacErlich I checked the system administrator's access to the field ProductFamily in the Asset object and it didn't have access. I assumed admins had access to everything but I learned that isn't always the case. Granted access and now the component works perfectly.
Thanks for the help!
